# ESLint rules for destructing arrays with unused variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint, destructuring

I have a function that returns an array with 2 values. In this instance, I only want to use the first one.
However, I cannot figure out the way that is accepted by ESLint to accomplish this.

I've tried the following ways, but there does not seem to be a way to satisfy all the rules.

```
// Triggers no-unused-vars rule
const [fileName, _] = createFile(objects, fileDirectory);
// Triggers comma-spacing rule
const [fileName,] = createFile(objects, fileDirectory);
// Triggers array-bracket-spacing rule
const [fileName, ] = createFile(objects, fileDirectory);
```

I would expect at least one of the methods to not trigger an ESLint rule violation, or there to be a different valid way of achieving the same.

Comment: `const [fileName] = createFile(objects, fileDirectory);`?

Comment: That works. I expected that would return the full array instead of just the first element.

Comment: `[fileName,]` and `[fileName, ]` both do the same thing but in both cases it's useless - you are taking the first value and skipping the second. You'd do the skip thing only need to use for something like `[fileName, , thirdValue]` - taking the first and third value skipping the second one.